# Go through each field in a struct dynamicly and change them

Tags: go, struct

How to go through all fields in a `struct` and edit/validate them on the fly?

Example:

```
func UrlEncodeStruct(s interface{}) {
  r := reflect.ValueOf(obj)
  for i := 0; i < r.NumField(); i++ {
    value := r.Field(i).String()
    value = url.QueryEscape(value)
    r.Field(i).SetString(value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify the struct value in the caller, change the function to take a pointer to the struct value. Otherwise, the posted function is correct for a struct containing only exported string fields.

```
func UrlEncodeStruct(s interface{}) {
    r := reflect.ValueOf(s).Elem()  // <-- note call to Elem() here
    for i := 0; i < r.NumField(); i++ {
        value := r.Field(i).String()
        value = url.QueryEscape(value)
        r.Field(i).SetString(value)
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var s someStructType
UrlEncodeStruct(&s)
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/ZWdIis-urwO)